# Chrome - Add "Install Application" in navigation bar for my website / application

Tags: html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, manifest

Recently, I've found new shortcut in Chrome/Chromium navbar on some websites.
Example available on [Netgate Forum](https://forum.netgate.com/)

It adds a new icon on right side of navigation bar.
[image: navbar]

On click, it gives a popup which invites to install application which is finally only a website shortcut with standalone container.  Actually, it's the same feature than `More Tools` > `Create Shortcut` menu.
[image].

I've checked Netgate forum HTML header, but I do not find the right syntax / feature to get this behavior on my own application.

On my point of view, it's a great new ability for PWA and a simplifier for end users.

Anyone know to do that ?
I find nothing about it.

Comment: This is a default behaviour of Chrome browser. If you have a valid service worker then you should see this by default.

Answer (score 0):

An actual answer for those coming from search engines:

1. Add to your HTML: `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>`
2. Create the `manifest.json` file with basic information, such as favicon and a 512px icon (optional):

```
{
  "short_name": "Flappy Bird",
  "name": "Flappy Bird: an HTML5 game",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "24x24"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

For more information on how the "web app manifest" works and what you can add to it, here is a decent reference article: https://web.dev/articles/add-manifest